# Google Sheets: Native formula to return slice of INDEX() values between two indices?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using only native Google Sheets functions (no scripts), how can I return a slice of values between two given indices from `=INDEX()` or another range reference?

**Example**

If:

```
=INDEX("Apple", "Banana", "Curant", "Delicious", "Eggplant", "Fruit")
```

and given indices are 3 and `=LEN(INDEX(...))`

then desired returned output is:

```
{"Curant", "Delicious", "Eggplant", "Fruit"}
```

**Note**

- Use of `=INDEX()` is preferable but other native solutions are great too.
- Use-case requires that the solution be able to take dynamic input as part of a larger function, rather than being given explicit ranges as input.
- Solution can be inclusive or exclusive of the given indices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the [=QUERY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function:

```
=QUERY(INDEX(A2:A), "SELECT A LIMIT "&(D2-C2+1)&" OFFSET "&(C2-1))
```

Where `C2` holds the initial index, and `D2` the final one.

In case you are using this function on an output of another function, you will have to replace the `A` in the `SELECT` clause for the `Col1` identifier:

```
=QUERY(INDEX(A2:A), "SELECT Col1 LIMIT "&(D2-C2+1)&" OFFSET "&(C2-1))
```

#### Examples

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

Comment: This is great, and bonus for the variations to allow for standalone and/or embedded functionality. Much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps not the best solution - but still a solution! [=QUERY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) is super powerful in Google Sheets, I highly recommend checking it out. Glad you liked my answer & I hope you have a good day ! :- )